# error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment in Macro

Tags: c

I have downloaded the source code for the open-source gt package on fedora and am attempting to compile it on Debian.
During compilation the following error in the title showed up for this piece of code in instrum.c:

```
#define READ_CHAR(thing) \
      thing = tmp[tmpindex++];
```

The full error report is as follows:

```
instrum.c: In function ‘load_instrument’:
instrum.c:944:13: error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment
  944 |       thing = tmp[tmpindex++];
      |             ^
instrum.c:1173:7: note: in expansion of macro ‘READ_CHAR’
 1173 |       READ_CHAR ((int8)sp->aps_parameter);
      |       ^~~~~~~~~
make[1]: *** [Makefile:335: instrum.o] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/classic/gt-0.4/src'
make: *** [Makefile:235: all] Error 2
```

the struct that sp is defined is as follows:

```
typedef struct {
  splen_t
    loop_start, loop_end, data_length;
  ...
  ...
  int32
    freq_scale, vibrato_delay;
  int8
    aps_parameter, sw_up, sw_down, sw_lokey, sw_hikey, sw_last;
} Sample;
```

Comment: Don't use a semicolon as the last character in a macro; it can lead to confusion.  It may not be related to your problem, though.

Comment: The result of a cast is not an l-value; you can't assign to it.  So, the `(int8)` cast means you cannot assign to that.  Why do you think the cast is remotely necessary? Now that you show the structure (which isn't [minimal](https://stackoverflow.com/mcve)!), `aps_parameter` is already an `int8` so the cast is totally superfluous — as well as erroneous!  Use `READ_CHAR(sp->aps_parameter);` (and remove the semicolon so you don't get confused by the errors when you write `if (x == y) READ_CHAR(sp->aps_parameter); else puts("Busted!");`

Comment: So try `READ_CHAR (sp->aps_parameter)`

Comment: @WeatherVane yes that fixed it, must be some modern gcc quirk, as this code is from 2004.

Comment: It's not a 'modern quirk'. Perhaps the code wasn't transcribed correctly, or didn't even compile originally.

Comment: The link in my upvoted comment is incorrect — the one in my answer is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The result of a cast is not an l-value; you can't assign to it. So, the `(int8)` cast means you cannot assign to that. Why do you think the cast is remotely necessary? Now that you show the structure (which isn't [minimal](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)!), `aps_parameter` is already an `int8` so the cast is totally superfluous — as well as erroneous! Use:

```
READ_CHAR(sp->aps_parameter);
```

Don't use a semicolon as the last character in a macro; it can lead to confusion. It is not directly related to your problem, though.
If you don't remove the semicolon, you will be confused by the errors when you write:

```
if (x == y)
    READ_CHAR(sp->aps_parameter);
else
    puts("Busted!");
```

See [Why use apparently meaningless `do`-`while` and `if`-`else` statements in macros?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/154136/15168) if you don't immediately see why the trailing semicolon is bad.  You can claim that "I would always use braces around the body of every `if`, `else` or loop statement — that would neutralize the bug, but it doesn't alter the fact that the trailing semicolon is a bug.